# CSS border-image is not working in Opera

Tags: css, cross-browser, opera

In my application I use `border image` in css, but it's not working in Opera. So how can it be supported by Opera?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use: `-o-border-image: url(...);` It's for Opera. You've got also `-moz-border-image: url(...);` for older Firefoxes and `-webkit-border-image: url(...);` for Safari, Konqueror, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is a sample [code](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image) from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp):

```
div
{
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
-moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
}
```

This is also nicely explained [here](http://www.css3files.com/border/).